# MySQL is not using indexes in this query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table which contains the following columns, and I created indexes for them:

`dt date` And `tm time`

Now I'm trying to tell if there's any records between certain timestamp:

```
explain SELECT count(*) from XX
where dt != CURRENT_DATE 
and tm BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '14:30:00'
```

And explain shows the `key` is NULL here, why is that?

If I substitute the first time value with number zero, the explain phrase shows the index is in use.

P.S I just tried more of it. If I wrap it with `exists` the index is in use again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create Multiple-Column Index.

```
Create index dt_tm_ix on XX (dt, tm)
```